# Can this integral be done smartly?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integral:

$${\int \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{a^{2}+b^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}{(a-x)^{2}+(b-y)^{2}} d y=\frac{2(a y-b x)}{(a-x)^{2}+(b-y)^{2}}}$$

I got the answer but I can't still solve this integral by myself.
How can it be done when you get only the left side of this equation?

Answer (score 0):

*Without any integration.*

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Big(\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}{(a-x)^{2}+(b-y)^{2}}\Big) =\frac{2 \left(a^3-2 a^2 x+a \left(b^2+x^2-y^2\right)+2 b x
   (y-b)\right)}{\left((a-x)^2+(b-y)^2\right)^2}$$

Let $$\frac{b-y}{a-x}=z \implies y=z (x-a)+b\implies dy=(x-a)\,dz$$
This makes the integrand to be
$$\frac{2 \left(-a z^2+2 b z+a\right)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2 (a-x)}$$ 
$$J=\int \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Big(\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}{(a-x)^{2}+(b-y)^{2}}\Big)\,dy =\frac{2}{(a-x)}\int \frac{-a z^2+2 b z+a}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}\,dz$$

Since the denominator is a square, you could check if the solution *could be*
$$I=\int \frac{-a z^2+2 b z+a}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}\,dz=\frac {P_n(z)}{z^2+1}$$ which would imply
$$\frac{-a z^2+2 b z+a}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}=\frac{\left(z^2+1\right) P_n'(z)-2 z P_n(z)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}$$ which, comparing the degrees, implies that $n=1$.

So let $P_1=\alpha + \beta z$
$$ -a z^2+2 b z+a=-\beta  z^2-2 \alpha  z+\beta\implies \beta=a \quad \text{and} \quad\alpha=-b$$

**It works !**

All of that make

$$J=\frac{2 (a z-b)}{\left(z^2+1\right) (a-x)}+C$$

Replace $z$ by $\frac{b-y}{a-x}$, simplify and you are done.

As you can see, I did not use integration at all.